# /var/log/syslog not rotating

Tags: syslog, logrotate

Our log file `/var/log/syslog` does not seem to be rotating, even though the logrotate config `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` exists:

```
/var/log/syslog
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
        reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
    rotate 4
    weekly
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```

See, the `syslog` log file is 600M with no old files or compressed.

```
-rw-r-----  1 syslog   adm    600M Nov  9 20:30 syslog
```

Comment: The rotation is based on logfile age, not size. Is it a day old yet?

Comment: Yes, server has been running for over 30 days. Actually, it appears that logrotate is not working at all, because there are no compressed or backup log files in `/var/log`. Anywhere to log for issues?

Comment: What happens if you run `logrotate` yourself? `sudo logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf` - the `-d` enables debug mode.

Comment: Running as `ubuntu` I see `error: skipping "/var/log/syslog" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.`. The permissions on `/var/log` are `775`.

Answer (score 17):

I found the problem, somehow `su` directive got removed from `/etc/logrotate.conf`, so needed to add:

```
# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the same `su` approach [mentioned by @Justin](https://askubuntu.com/a/696007/1034204), except I had to add it to he service-specific logrotate config file (instead of the global logrotate config file):

1. Determine the `su` user/group to use from the global logrotate config file

   `grep 'su ' "/etc/logrotate.conf"`
2. Edit rsyslog logrotate config

   `vi "/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog"`
3. Prepend the `su` line (from step 1) to the top of the file:

   `su root syslog`
4. Test for errors

   `logrotate --debug --force /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog 2>&1 | grep -i cron`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it seems to have been caused by some kind of incompatibility between the `logrotate` configuration and the new `systemd` replacement for `sysv`/`init.d`

I had to edit the `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` and replace

```
invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
```

with

```
systemctl kill -s HUP --kill-who=main rsyslog.service
```

the previous line looked like it was working, and said so, but did not manage to get rsyslog to reopen its logfiles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering 8-years later as this is still a top result in search engines.

(1) As @Justin mentions, the first solution is to ensure your `/etc/logrotate.conf` is performing and `su` to the same permissions as the log files:

```
su root syslog
```

(2) If you are running inside a container, you may need to update your `logrotate.service` to disable certain kernel protections (this is a common reason for namespace failures, as a container doesn't have permission to access the kernel in a way to enable these features). Although you can enable `nesting` on your container, this may cause other user-space issues. To simply disable the kernel protections inside the container:

```bash
sed -ie 's/^ProtectKernel/\#ProtectKernel/g' /lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service
systemctl daemon-reload
```

(3) If the above steps fail, some systems may need "/var/log" explicitly added to the service file:

```bash
echo "ReadWritePaths=/var/log" >> /lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service
systemctl daemon-reload
```

(4) If the above steps fail, you may need to disable other system protections in `/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service`, which may be any of the following:

```
LockPersonality=true
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true
PrivateDevices=true
PrivateTmp=true
ProtectClock=true
ProtectControlGroups=true
ProtectHostname=true
ProtectKernelLogs=true
ProtectKernelModules=true
ProtectKernelTunables=true
ProtectSystem=full
RestrictNamespaces=true
RestrictRealtime=true
```

Each of which may be set to "true", and the lines may be changed to "false" or commented-out. It would be wise to go through one-by-one to see which line(s) are causing the issue on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Samuel's comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160744/885982), modified `/usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate`

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
    systemctl kill -s HUP --kill-who=main rsyslog.service
else
    invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
fi
```

Comment: What system are you running? I did not find that file on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, kernel 4.15.18-21-pve x86_64